# Re-Map the Application Switcher in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab

I'm a mac-user in the office, but now i have a windows laptop for travel.

I've already employed SharpKeys to swap left ctrl and left alt, giving me mac-like access to most common shortcuts. This really got me 96% of the way to having a seamless transition between mac and windows keyboards.

My issue now is the application switcher, which i use constantly on both mac and Windows. Now that my keys are re-mapped i have to reach for left ctrl + tab to call up the app switcher.

Any bright ideas for how to leave my ctrl and alt keys remapped AND use ctrl + tab to call up the app switcher?

AutoHotKey looks promising, but not sure that it will do it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This AutoHotKey mapping should make `Left control` + `Tab` behave exactly like `Alt` + `Tab` behaves:

```
LCtrl & Tab::AltTab
```

Comment: I don't actually have a Win machine to test this so please comment here if it doesn't work.

Comment: you are a god!!!!  Problem solved.  Quickly and elegantly!